# WiXToolsets error PYRO0001 : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: wix

I have an issue when creating a patch, using pyro tool. I am not sure if this is a WiX tool defect, or I am doing something wrong. When executing the pyro.exe, my release builder crashes with the output from the pyro tool as below:

---

Windows Installer XML Toolset Patch Builder version 3.11.0.1701
Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved.

pyro.exe : error PYRO0001 : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Exception Type: System.NullReferenceException

Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.MediaRow.get_LastSequence()
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Patch.AttachTransforms(ArrayList transforms)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Tools.Pyro.Run(String[] args)

---

And, this is the execution sequence of WiX tools I am using to build a patch:

1. candle.exe  -out Patch.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixNetFxExtension -arch x86
2. light.exe -out Product_1.wixout Product_1.wixobj -xo -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixNetFxExtension
3. light.exe -out Product_2.wixout Product_2.wixobj -xo -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixNetFxExtension
4. torch.exe -out Diff.wixmst Product_wixout Product_2.wixout -p -xi -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixNetFxExtension
5. light.exe -out Patch.wixmsp Patch.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixNetFxExtension
6. pyro.exe -outPatch.msp Patch.wixmsp -t MyPatch Diff.wixmst

Please advise.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The current workaround for this issue (that is not documented, for whatever terrible reason), is to change the way media is defined in your product you are creating a patch for.

So, instead of using the following in your Product element (which is the recommended approach...):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product ...>
     ...
     <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
     ...
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

You will need to replace the `MediaTemplate` element with the `Media` element, like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product ...>
     ...
     <Media Id="1" Cabinet="MyProduct.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
     ...
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

For more advanced installations, the `Media` element will be more difficult to use than `MediaTemplate`, but there is decent documentation on these elements out there. What I've shown is for the simplest type of install. I think this issue cropped up when the WiX Toolset team introduced the newer, easier to use `MediaTemplate`, and somehow the patching use-case was missed in testing.

Hopefully this helps anyone else who is trying to use WiX Patching and getting this nasty exception.